# SASS: Is there a way to cusomize the sass syntax?

Tags: css, sass

I have an scss function like this

```
@function dpx($size) {
  @return calc(var(--dpx, 10px) * #{$size});
}
```

This is working fine like this:

```
h1 {
  font-size: dpx(1.6);
}
```

But I think it's a little verbose since I need to use it everywhere and I want to make this function more feels like a unit.

I know sass is a precompiler, can I somehow to make the following syntax compiles into `dpx(1.6)`?

```
h1 {
  font-size: 1.6dpx;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could centralize font-sizing using CSSVariables (no SCSS required)

```css
* {
  font-size: calc(var(--dpx, 10px) * var(--fs));
}

.a { --fs: 1; } 
.b { --fs: 2; } 
.c { --fs: 3; } 
.d { --fs: 4; }
```

```html
<h2 class="a">lorem</h2>
<h2 class="b">lorem</h2>
<h2 class="c">lorem</h2>
<h2 class="d">lorem</h2>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what I actually want is a relative unit, and I can control the definition of `dpx` in different context: `--dpx: 20px; margin-top: 2dpx;`, make it equivolent to `margin-top: 40px;`. It's similar to `em` hack: `font-size: 20px; margin-top: 2em`, but by doing so the text size is changed unwantedly. What's the best way to achieve a relative unit?